# I'm getting this error, ERROR NullInjectorError: R3InjectorError(D)[Zs -> Zs]: NullInjectorError: No provider for Zs

Tags: angular, angular16

I added all services to my app module provider and All services have this
`@Injectable({ providedIn: "root", })`
But still, I'm getting this error. I tried all the way[image: error image screenshot]

ERROR NullInjectorError: R3InjectorError(D)[Zs -> Zs]:    NullInjectorError: No provider for Zs!

My app module code

```
providers: [
{
  provide: LocationStrategy,
  useClass: HashLocationStrategy
},
{
  provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS,
  useClass: HttpConfigInterceptor,
  multi: true
},
```

],

My service code look like this.
[image: My service code look like]

Comment: It would be helpful if you could provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) that shows the problem or error you're having, ideally in an online code editor like [Stackblitz](https://www.stackblitz.com).

Comment: I updated my question details. You can view it.

Answer (score 0):

Run your application in dev mode, you would you be able to find exact dependency to inject in providers - add following code in to angular.json under configurations
"development": {
"optimization": false,
"outputHashing": "all",
"sourceMap": false,
"namedChunks": false,
"aot": true,
"extractLicenses": true,
"vendorChunk": false,
"buildOptimizer": true
},

to run code in dev mode.